# How do I debug my Unity Scope?

Tags: application-development, scopes

I've started writing a scope for the Unity Dash, but it seems not to return results.

I'd like to find out why: how can I debug my scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scopes are normally activated by DBus, which makes them a bit trickier to debug. But at the same time they’re normal processes and can be run manually so that any warnings or debug statements are easily visible.

The recommendation is to start your scope manually from the command line and use the traditional debugging tools, such as **gdb**, **valgrind**, **strace** etc. Since scopes use DBus for internal IPC, a DBus monitor tool (such as Bustle) can be handy if you suspect any problems in this area.

[image]

You can also use the libunity-tool debugger, simply executing it's GUI from the command line `libunity-tool -g`. Just execute your scope manually or from the Dash, find the DBus path in the initial drop-down box, submit a search query and watch the results.